# Chat sucks without the new image upload dialog. It should have the new image upload dialog. The one that allows you to paste images directly into it

Tags: feature-request, chat, uploader

The new image upload dialog is awesome and I love it.

Will we get it on chat as well?

Comment: @shog Such exemplary answers.

Comment: @Shog Eh, just used the default :P Shall give away 500 points on next bounty. You totally deserve a hat for hijacking a bounty though!

Comment: @Shog9 Such description. So hats. Very rep. Much off topic. Wow.

Comment: The Shog has awaken (again)!